# Google Spreadsheet - Get records from Zoho

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, zoho

From, a google spreadshhet, I'm trying to collect records from Zoho.

I've tested this code:

```js
var urlgetRecords = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords?newFormat=1&authtoken=00000&scope=crmapi&selectColumns=Leads(First Name,Last Name,Email)&fromIndex=1&toIndex=2&sortColumnString=First Name&sortOrderString=desc';

var jsonResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlgetgetRecords);
```

This is what obtain:

> {"response":{"result":{"Leads":{"row":[{"no":"1","FL":[{"content":"1412559000000441145","val":"LEADID"},{"content":"Víctor","val":"First
>   Name"},{"content":"Aguilera Moreno","val":"Last
>   Name"},{"content":"v-aguilera@hotmail.com","val":"Email"}]},{"no":"2","FL":[{"content":"1412559000000308001","val":"LEADID"},{"content":"Victor","val":"First
>   Name"},{"content":"Porta","val":"Last
>   Name"},{"content":"vporta@test.es","val":"Email"}]}]}},"uri":"/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords"}}

Please, How can write every row in this response in a spreadsheet?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write ZOHO data to Google spreadsheet.  To use the code below, edit the sheet tab name in the `getSheetByName('Sheet2')` method to the sheet tab where you want the data to be appended to.

I've tested this code and it works:

```
function writeZohoToSheet(zohoDataObject) {
  var zohoDataObject = {"response":
                        {"result":
                         {"Leads":
                          {"row":
                           [{"no":"1","FL":[
                              {"content":"12345678IDNumber","val":"LEADID"},
                              {"content":"Víctor","val":"First Name"},
                              {"content":"Aguilera Moreno","val":"Last Name"},
                              {"content":"v-agEmailTest@hotmail.com","val":"Email"}]
                            },
                            {"no":"2","FL":[
                              {"content":"987654321IDNumber","val":"LEADID"},
                              {"content":"Victor","val":"First Name"},
                              {"content":"Porta","val":"Last Name"},
                              {"content":"someEmail@test.es","val":"Email"}]
                            }
                           ]
                          }
                         },"uri":"/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords"}};

  var rows = zohoDataObject.response.result.Leads.row;
  Logger.log('rows: ' + rows);
  Logger.log('rows.length: ' + rows.length);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var array = [], thisRow, thisContent, innerObj;

  for (var r in rows) {
    array = []; //reset
    thisRow = rows[r];
    thisContent = thisRow.FL;

    array.push(r);

    for (var i=0;i<thisContent.length;i+=1) {
      innerObj = thisContent[i];
      array.push(innerObj.val);
      array.push(innerObj.content);
    };

    sh.appendRow(array);
  }; 
};
```

You would call the function with:

```
writeZohoToSheet(jsonResponse);
```

Remove the "hard coded" object literal, or comment it out in order to pass in the retrieved object.

Answer (score 1):

The Sandy Good's code is perfect. 
I've had to add two more lines.

Finally the code that works is:

```js
var urlgetRecords = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords?newFormat=1&authtoken=' + authToken + '&scope=crmapi&selectColumns=Leads(First Name,Last Name,Email)&fromIndex=1&toIndex=2&sortColumnString=First Name&sortOrderString=desc';
var jsonResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlgetRecords);
 var jsonText = jsonResponse.getContentText();
 var objetoFinal = JSON.parse(jsonText);
 writeZohoToSheet(objetoFinal);
```

Thank you very much for your help @SandyGood